# How to get all index value from array including same numbers?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, arraylist

```
copyarray = yAxisdata.slice(0);  
length=yAxisdata.length;   
for (k = 0; k <length-1; k++)
{ 
     maxvalue = copyarray[k];
     indexvalue = yAxisdata.indexOf(maxvalue);
}
```

`I am trying to find the index value of the data from array who's contain 800 data approximately and it is also contain lots of same value.`

Above codes are used to get the index value of all the elements which is available inside the array. but the problem is if array have a multiple same value at that time this code shows only index of first value and skip the same values in array and show the index of the other value.

Comment: `indexvalue = k`?

Comment: It is javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% familiar with javascript but i think below will do the trick

```
copyarray = yAxisdata.slice(0);  
length=yAxisdata.length;  
var result;
var maxvalue = 0;
var counter;

for (k = 0; k <length-1; k++)
{ 
    maxvalue = copyarray[k];
    result = [];
    counter = 0;

    for(x = 0; x < length -1; x++)
    {
        if(copyarray[x] == maxvalue)
        {
            result[counter] = x;
            counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

The C# version would be

```
int[] copyarray = yAxisdata.Select(ch => ch - '0').ToArray();

List<int> result = new List<int>();
int maxvalue = 0; 

for (int k = 0; k < copyarray.Count() - 1; k++)
{
    maxvalue = copyarray[k];
    
    // Alternative code
    // result = copyarray.Select((value, index) => new { value, index }).Where((a) => a.value == maxvalue).Select((a) => a.index).ToList();
    result = new List<int>();

    for(x = 0; x < copyarray.Count() - 1; x++)
    {
        if (copyarray[x] == maxvalue)
        {
            result.Add(x);
        }
    }
}
```

The result variable is now an array with all the indexes containing the maxvalue